# How can I rebinding after binding in Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I wanna know rebinding in knockout.js.

first, I already binding to data in"edit".
but I want to reset the data by clicking on it.

If I reset the data, I have to binding in "edit"

How can I rebinding? not ko.cleanNode.

```js
var initData={ 
    price: ko.observable("0"),
    volume: ko.observable("0")
};

ko.applyBindings(initData, document.getElementById("edit"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="edit">
  price : <input data-bind="value: price" />
  volume : <input data-bind="value: volume" />

<div><a href="#" data-bind="click: InitDataClick">Init</a></div>
</div>
```

};

Comment: Generally you don't need to rebind in knockout, you just update your viewmodel.  It's a little unclear what you're asking though, and your code snippet is currently erroring - could you fix it and provide a little more detail about what you want to achieve?

Comment: How should I fix it? I don't know..

Comment: I just wanna reset the data after click "InitDataClick"

Answer (score 1):

- Add the `InitDataClick` to your viewmodel to which you `applyBindings`
- Inside the method, reset the two properties of `initData` by calling them with the initial value
- Make sure your inputs are bound to the data object by using the `with` binding

```js
var initData = { 
  price: ko.observable("0"),
  volume: ko.observable("0")
};

ko.applyBindings({
  initData,
  InitDataClick: function() {
    initData.price("0");
    initData.volume("0");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: initData">
  price : <input data-bind="value: price" />
  volume : <input data-bind="value: volume" />
</div>
<div><a href="#" data-bind="click: InitDataClick">Init</a></div>
```